# What does the final signoff of "Libro gordo de Petete" mean?

Tags: traducción

Each episode of the children's series ends with the following:

> El libro gordo te enseña,
> el libro gordo entretiene,
> y yo te digo contenta,
> hasta la clase que viene.

https://youtu.be/L2IT_SD4V9A?t=130

What does "y yo te digo contenta" mean? It's a strange wording.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I think I've figured it out. It's a dependent clause, so they're saying something like:

> and I tell you contented, "until next class!"

Comment: I think "happy" would be a better translation rather than "contented", but you got the meaning.

Comment: and I am happy to tell you, until next lesson

Answer (score 0):

I say you happy: - Y yo te digo contenta:

---

"Until next class" - "Hasta la próxima clase"